# Creating test users for Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to programmatically create users for testing with Azure AD B2C?  The only way to create users that I am aware of is through website signup.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Azure AD B2C Graph API allows CRUD operations on users.

You can create a user by sending a "POST" request to the /users endpoint.

The following documentation demonstrates this with a "B2CGraphClient" utils written in C# :
[Azure AD B2C: Use the Graph](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser)
(see GitHub link in the page to download the sample code)

Please note there are two types of user account in Azure AD B2C : "local accounts" and "work or school accounts".
[Required parameters vary upon the account type you need.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#CreateUser)

Comment: Did you manage to do this on a B2C tenant created via the portal?

I followed this tutorial which mentions that you can only run graph operations on a B2C app created via Powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Using the sample client, I get an authorization error for any B2C tenant I created via the portal. I think this may be due to confusion on where to find or generate the Client Secret value. Can you advise on this?

Comment: The portal has been upgraded to add tenant using azure ad portal, please check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet